# Cocos2d-x Android NDK debug Error (9): Bad file descriptor?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

There is a crash when I am developing an Android application using `Cocos2d-x`. So I am using `ndk-stack` and I get this error:

```
D:\Android\android-ndk-r8e>adb logcat | ndk-stack.exe -sym e:\graduation_project
\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects\Test_py\proj.android\obj\local\armeabi\
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/mysid/toro:4.2.2/JDQ39/573038:user/release-keys'
pid: 9911, tid: 9950, name: Thread-1096  >>> com.einverne.test_py <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr ff7a8390
Stack frame #00  pc 0001055e  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+1729): Unable to ope
n symbol file e:\graduation_project\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects\Test_py\proj.androi
d\obj\local\armeabi\/libc.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
Stack frame #01  pc 0000dcc7  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10): Unable to open sy
mbol file e:\graduation_project\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects\Test_py\proj.android\ob
j\local\armeabi\/libc.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
Stack frame #02  pc 002a4bff  /data/app-lib/com.einverne.test_py-1/libcocos2dcpp
.so (cocos2d::unzOpenCurrentFile3(void*, int*, int*, int, char const*)+482): Rou
tine unzOpenCurrentFile3 in e:\graduation_project\cocos2d-x-2.1.5/cocos2dx/suppo
rt/zip_support/unzip.cpp:1494
Stack frame #03  pc 002a4d9f  /data/app-lib/com.einverne.test_py-1/libcocos2dcpp
.so (cocos2d::unzOpenCurrentFile(void*)+10): Routine unzOpenCurrentFile in e:\gr
aduation_project\cocos2d-x-2.1.5/cocos2dx/support/zip_support/unzip.cpp:1677
Stack frame #04  pc 002a302d  /data/app-lib/com.einverne.test_py-1/libcocos2dcpp
.so (cocos2d::ZipFile::getFileData(std::string const&, unsigned long*)+76): Rout
ine getFileData in e:\graduation_project\cocos2d-x-2.1.5/cocos2dx/support/zip_su
pport/ZipUtils.cpp:556
Stack frame #05  pc 002943c5  /data/app-lib/com.einverne.test_py-1/libcocos2dcpp
.so (cocos2d::CCFileUtilsAndroid::getFileData(char const*, char const*, unsigned
 long*)+76): Routine getFileData in e:\graduation_project\cocos2d-x-2.1.5/cocos2
dx/platform/android/CCFileUtilsAndroid.cpp:126
Stack frame #06  pc 00173267  /data/app-lib/com.einverne.test_py-1/libcocos2dcpp
.so (CLuaScriptReader::RunScriptFile(char const*, char*, char*)+46): Routine Run
ScriptFile in jni/../../Classes/LuaScriptReader.cpp:318
Stack frame #07  pc 00172129  /data/app-lib/com.einverne.test_py-1/libcocos2dcpp
.so (JudgeManager::getResult(std::string, std::string, CharacterEntity*, std::st
ring)+200): Routine getResult in jni/../../Classes/JudgeManager.cpp:51
```

When I come back to my code.

```
bool CLuaScriptReader::RunScriptFile(const char *filename,char* ret_string,char *name){
    if( m_plua == NULL || ret_string == NULL || filename == NULL ) return false;
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32
    char filebuff[MAX_LUA_FILE_LEN] = "";
    char line[1024] = "";
    FILE* fpFile = fopen(filename,"r");
    if( fpFile == NULL ) {
        printf("can not find file %s\n",filename);
        return false;
    }
    while( fgets(line, 1024, fpFile) != NULL) {
        strcat(filebuff,line);
    }
    fclose(fpFile);
    RunScriptBuffer(filebuff,ret_string,name);
#endif
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
    unsigned long int size = 0;
    unsigned char* filebuff = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(filename,"r",&size);
    CCString* ccStr = CCString::createWithData(filebuff,size);
    RunScriptBuffer(ccStr->getCString(),ret_string,name);
#endif
    return true;
}
```

Error happened in this line:

```
unsigned char* filebuff = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(filename,"r",&size);
```

However, I am always using this code to read file under Android. Class `CLuaScriptReader` can be found [here](https://github.com/einverne/writing/blob/master/Classes/LuaScriptReader.cpp#L318)

Answer (score 0):

How do you compile the files?

It seems a problem with the script. The lines:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr ff7a8390
Stack frame #00  pc 0001055e  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+1729): Unable to ope
n symbol file e:\graduation_project\cocos2d-x-2.1.5\projects\Test_py\proj.androi
d\obj\local\armeabi\/libc.so. Error (9): Bad file descriptor
```

Signal 11 --> A memory fail, and the path go to nowhere. / are for paths in UNIX system, and \ to WINDOWS system, so something is wrong to find libc.so

A Bad file descriptor is a linux, if you get this error message while trying to access a file, the most prominent causes are file system corruption or damaged disk block(s). In such situations, you also get write errors.